# Reset gcc version from 11.3 to 11.2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++

[image]

I wanted to compile an assignment, but the version of my gcc and g++ had updated to 11.3 instead of 11.2. How can I reset them to 11.2? Thanks. I am using ubuntu22.04 on VMWare WorkStation.

[image]
I searched the web and found this way. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with aptitude, it worked better for me.

First get a list of the available versions :

```
sudo apt list gcc-11
```

Then install the version you want, so for me :

```
sudo aptitude install gcc-11=11.2.0-19ubuntu1
```

Aptitude will propose several ways to do this, choose the one that downgrades gcc and related packages.